# 1970's or early 80's SF Novel Underwater Cities dealing with Cold War

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a SF novel back in 1970's. Cold War was still on; US and Soviets had underwater domed cities; both domed enemies had to band together to prevent their destruction as a single blast near their dome would wipe out the entire city. I'd love to find a copy but can't remember the title or author.

The Underwater Domed Cities were colonies of USA and USSR; they joined together renouncing their founding countries and became a new nation IIRC. As it wouldn't even take a nuke to destroy the cities, any large explosion could take down a dome, destroying it and its inhabitants at once.

*The Dragon in the Sea* aka *Under Pressure* by Frank Herbert [has been eliminated](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/ryzu46/1970s_or_early_80s_sf_novel_underwater_cities/).

Comment: Too recent, but https://timothysjohnston.com/warbeneathreviews/

Comment: @MaddAndroid - Hi, welcome to the site. Can you clarify who or what the domed cities banded together against though?

Comment: [*Clash by Night*](http://www.fantasyliterature.com/reviews/clash-by-night/) is a short story with similar themes: Domed cities, war, domes must be protected.  Probably not what you are looking for.  It is older than the 1970s, it takes place on Venus after a war has destroyed the Earth, no nationalities (Russians/Americans,) just the Keeps (domes) and the Free Companies (mercenaries who carry out the battles between the keeps.)  It's a good story, though - even though the reviewer in the link didn't like it.

Comment: Please don't put "solved" in the post title. Instead, Accept the Answer! Click on the gray check mark beside the answer.

Answer (score 20):

This sounds like the plot of [Dome World](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/3666983) by Dean McLaughlin, though in Dome World the potential war is between America and an African empire not the USSR. Apart from this the plot description fits, and it was published in 1971 so it fits your memory of the date you read it.

[image: Dome World]

The protagonist is *Danial Mason* who is in charge of *Wilmington Dome*. The domes were originally constructed to mine vanadium, and as war between the USA and the African empire looms it is realised that the domes could become targets and that:

> All it would take is a single (thermonuclear) bomb to crack one, and after that it’s all over.

Mason reacts by declaring Wilmington Dome an independent state, then he reaches out to the other domes to join him and form a new independent union called *The League*.

In the second half of the book it jumps into the future where The League exists and the USA and Africa have now joined forces to reconquer it. To be honest I lost interest around this time and I don't recall how it ends.

If you want to check any specific points you remember the book is [on Google Books](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Dome_World/yBUxAAAAIAAJ) and *search inside* is available.

Comment: That's it thank you so much. Now the search for the old paperback begins